# How properly close thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having trouble understanding threads in Python. I have this program:

```
import _thread, time

def print_loop():
    num = 0
    while 1:
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        time.sleep(1)

_thread.start_new_thread(print_loop, ())

time.sleep(10)
```

And my question is if I need to close the thread print_loop, because it looks to me that both threads end when the main thread ends. Is this proper way to handle threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, avoid using the low-level API unless you absolutely have to. The `threading` module is preferred over `_thread`. In general in Python, avoid anything starting with an underscore.

Now, the method you are looking for is called `join`. I.e.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

stop = False

def print_loop():
    num = 0
    while not stop:
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=print_loop)
thread.start()

time.sleep(10)

stop = True
thread.join()
```